# Why does .__index only return the function from the subclass instead of the base class

Tags: oop, lua

```lua
item = {y = 21}

function item:new(o)
    o = o or {}
    setmetatable(o, self)
    self.__index = self
    return o
end

function item:Run()
    print("item running")
end

berry = item:new{x = 52}

function berry:new(o)
    o = o or {}
    setmetatable(o, self)
    self.__index = self
    return o
end
function berry:Run()
    print("berry is running")
    self.__index:Run()
end

berry:new{b = 32}:Run()
```

The output is infinitely printing "berry is running" when it should be printing "berry is running" followed by "item running". If I change `self.__index` to `self.__index.__index` or even to `self.__index.__index.__index`, the output still infinitely prints "berry is running". How can I rectify this? Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Replace `self.__index:Run()` with `getmetatable(self):Run()`

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff "item running" is being printed once but "berry is running" is being printed twice instead of once. Also would this still work if I create a further subclass from berry?

Comment: My `Run()` is executed once for every level in hierarchy.  That's why there are 3 messages: from subclass, from class `berry` and from class `item`

Answer (score 0):

You have overridden the `Run` function of your `item` in your `berry`, this makes it more difficult to reach. this override causes your infinite loop as `self.__index` is a reference **to** `self` which is a `berry`. Now that `Run` is defined in berry `__index` will no longer be called when `berry` is indexed with `Run`

So your `berry:Run` function is essentially

```
function berry:Run()
    print("berry is running")
    berry:Run()
end
```

---

I suggest you change your `berry:Run` function, and specifically call `item.Run` in it:

```
function berry:Run()
    print("berry is running")
    item.Run(self) -- specifically call item.Run and pass it self.
end
```

This will give you the desired output of:

> berry is running
>
> item running

---

Alternatively you can persevere the `item:Run` function by defining it in berry before Run:

```
berry.ParentRun. = berry.Run -- this will cause __index to run and get item:Run
function berry:Run()         -- This now defines berry.Run. now __index will no longer run for berry.Run
    print("berry is running")
    self:ParentRun()         
end
```

---

Bonus note:

The reason you saw

> berry is running
>
> berry is running
>
> item running

from the suggestion in the comments is because the order of runs would be

```
object:Run() -- this calls berry passing the self of object
```

print our first berry is running

now we grab the metatable of that object, which is berry and call it's run

```
berry:Run()
```

print our second berry is running

and finally we get the metatable of berry which is item and call it's run

```
item:Run()
```

print item running